# Connecting to Amazon Work Mail with Delphi and Indy

Tags: email, delphi, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo, amazon-workmail

I have an IMAP4 client that works fine connected to RackSpace, but the client is moving to Amazon work mail.

Per Amazon published instructions:

```
Connect to your IMAP Client Application

You can connect any IMAP-compatible client software to Amazon WorkMail by providing the following information: 

Type of account IMAP 
Protocol IMAPS 
Port 993 
Secure connection Required;SSL 
Incoming username Email address associated with your Amazon WorkMail account 
Incoming password Your password 
Incoming server The endpoint matching the region where your mailbox is located: • us-east-1 imap.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com
```

The only operation I have coded is `IMAPClient.Connect();`

It returns a status of "Connected", but the program hangs after that.  I have followed the thread through the component source and found it is waiting for a return from Amazon in the function `TIdIMAP4.GetResponse: string;` It just hangs there for a very long time and then throws a "Connection Gracefully Closed" exception.

Delphi 10.2

Indy 10.6.2.5366

What am I missing?

My settings are:

```
var
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

with IMAPClient do
begin
  Name := 'IMAPClient';
  OnStatus := IMAPClientStatus;
  IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  OnDisconnected := IMAPClientDisconnected;
  OnConnected := IMAPClientConnected;
  Password := 'EmailTest1236';
  Port := 993;
  Username := 'emailTest.1236@foo.bar.com';
  Host := 'imap.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com';
  UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
  SASLMechanisms := <>;
  MilliSecsToWaitToClearBuffer := 10;
end;

IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);

with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do
begin
  Name := 'IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1';
  OnStatus := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1Status;
  Destination := 'imap.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com:993';
  Host := 'imap.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com';
  MaxLineAction := maException;
  Port := 993;
  BoundPort := 993;
  DefaultPort := 0;
end;
```

The email account and password are bogus.  I can not give out a real one.

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket,
  IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdMessageClient,
  IdIMAP4, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    IMAPClient: TIdIMAP4;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IMAPClientStatus(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
      const AStatusText: string);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IMAPClient.Connect();
end;

procedure TForm4.IMAPClientStatus(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add(AStatusText);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `TIdImap4.UseTLS` property from `utUseRequireTLS` to `utUseImplicitTLS`.  IMAP port 993 expects the client to send an SSL/TLS handshake as soon as the socket is connected, before the server can send the IMAP greeting (encrypted) to the client.  `utUseRequireTLS` does not do that handshake, `utUseImplicitTLS` does.  Your client is freezing because it is not sending the handshake, and is trying to read an (unencrypted) greeting that the server is not sending.

On a side note, you should not be setting most of the SSLIOHandler's properties that you are currently setting.  The only properties you should be setting manually are `Name` (optional), `SSLOptions`, and desired event handlers.  The rest of the properties are handled by Indy internally for you (primarily by `Connect()`), so you don't need to mess around with them.